# Hypergeometric conditional probability

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function

Question:

Bowl 1 contains 8 red and 6 black marbles. Four marbles are randomly selected from bowl 1 and placed in bowl 2. Then one marble is randomly selected from bowl 2.

What is the probability that two red and two black marbles are selected from bowl 1, given that 1 black marble is selected from bowl 2?

$\Large \frac{\frac{{6 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}}{{14 \choose 4}}}{\frac{{6 \choose 1}{8 \choose 3}+{6 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 3}{8 \choose 1}+{6 \choose 4}}{{14 \choose 4}}}$

$= \Large\frac{420}{931}$

I don't think this is correct but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but not quite.

You have  calculated the probability that two red and two black marbles were selected from bowl one, given that one of the marbles so selected was black.   That isn't *quite* what you want.

You want the probability that that two red and two black marbles were selected from bowl one (into bowl two), *when given* that one black marble *was subsequently* selected from bowl two.   That is *not* actually the same condition.

> Knowing that "one black marble was drawn from bowl 2" is *not* the same as knowing that "at least one black marble was placed into bowl 2".   You know *more* information!   You know that "at least one black marble was placed into the bowl *and* that one of these was selected".   That extra information affects the conditional probability.

Now, how do you think you might take **this** *condition* into account?

---

Let $A=2$ be the event that two black marbles were selected from bowl one; and $B=1$ the event that a black marble was then selected from bowl two.   Then using conditional probability (Bayes' Rule):

$$\begin{align}P(A=2\mid B=1) & = \frac{P(A=2)\mathsf P(B=1\mid A=2)}{\sum_{n=0}^{4}P(A=n)\mathsf P(B=1\mid A=n)}\end{align}$$

Remember, if you transfer $n$ black marbles into bowl two, there is a $\tfrac n 4$ probability of selecting one of them again.   That is $\mathsf P(B=1\mid A=n)= \tfrac n 4$

So $\mathsf P(A=n)\mathsf P(B=1\mid A=n) = \frac{\binom{6}{n}\binom{8}{4-n}}{\binom{14}{4}}\frac{n}{4}$

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstand. If one black marble is selected from bowl 2, doesn't that mean that either 1, 2, 3, or 4 black marbles were moved from bowl 1 to bowl 2?

Edit: So would that mean that since 1 is definitely black, we can do $\frac{{5 \choose 1}{8 \choose 2}}{13 \choose 3}$

Comment: I'm not sure if my previous comment is correct or not, but that is the alternative way I thought of doing the question. Since we already know that one marble must be black, we then look for the probability of 1 additional black marble and two red marbles selected from the 13 remaining marbles in bowl 1.

Comment: @statsguyz Knowing that "one black marble was drawn from bowl 2" is *not* the same as knowing that "at least one black marble was placed into bowl 2".  You know *more*.  You know that "at least one black marble was placed into the bowl *and* that one of these was selected".